# Setup Internal GIT Repo

Tags: git

My goal is to setup a GIT repo on a Windows network that can:

1. Be pushed to by a number of users from their machines
2. Can be updated directly and have users pull down the updates

I have read a few examples but there are some points I am confused on.

Here is what I have so far:

**ON THE SERVER**

```
mkdir project.git
cd project.git
git init --bare --shared
git remote add origin file:///C:/pathToThisDir/project.git
```

Questions:

1. If I use *--bare* does this mean that I can only push to the repo and I can not change into that directly, make a change and then commit?
2. What does the *--shared* param do and what happens if I don't user it?
3. I don't understand why I need to *"git remote add..."* I want this location to be the remote that all other users push and pull from.

The next step would be for a user to clone the repo.

**ON THE USER COMPUTER**

```
git clone [PATH TO REPO]
make commit 
push
pull
```

Question:

1. What URL or file path does the user use to clone the repo?

Comment: I don't think you need `git remote add origin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers to your questions:

1. Yes, you can only push to the repo and not make changes. Since a repo can have multiple branches, a bare repo doesn't keep one version available to edit, as we have locally.
2. --shared param by default adds group permissions to the repo such that other users can also write to the folder. If you are setting up on a windows shared drive, this might not be needed.
3. You are right, you don't need to add a origin in a bare repo.
4. To clone the repo from a windows shared drive, you can use the shared workgroup path, beginning with `//SERVER-NAME` Here's a gist that has an example: https://gist.github.com/zarzen/e60ff6824ff7c7424e25

Comment: Consider putting the example in the answer? Not behind a link

Comment: @evolutionxbox The OP hasn't even mentioned if he is using a shared workgroup, or what his server configuration might be. The example is just for overall reference

Comment: I'm not sure what the environment will be. I'm hoping I can map a drive to the server and then use the //SERVER syntax.